# Why is Timeshift not on the official Ubuntu repos?

Tags: backup, restore

It has become a standard, isn't there a way to include it in the discover store?

Comment: As of 19.04, it is in the repos now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To briefly answer the question... it's because Timeshift is the work of a individual software developer.

**Note: As of 19.04, it is in the repos now.**

For those who don't know what Timeshift is...

The closest thing to a Windows-like restore point is by using `Timeshift`. I use it to save snapshots to an external USB hard drive. Although it can, it's normally not used for backing up your /home directory, just system-level changes. Use `Backups` (Déjà Dup) for backing up /home files.

> Timeshift is a system restore utility which takes snapshots of the system at regular intervals. These snapshots can be restored at a later date to undo system changes. Creates incremental snapshots using rsync or BTRFS snapshots using BTRFS tools.

More information at https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

For pre-19.04 add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

And install it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install timeshift
```

Comment: Sorry to jump in on this but if Timeshift is incremental, can you delete previous snapshots or do you have to keep them all?

Comment: @kerry I believe that the answer is, no, you can't delete previous snapshots, as they use symbolic links to previous snapshots, to keep the total sizes lower.

Comment: thanks very much, one last thing, do you know what happens if you reboot during a snapshot, does it mess up, resume on reboot, delete ?

Comment: @kerry Don't know. I'd assume that the last snapshot would be incomplete or corrupt, and probably should be deleted. Go to the web site and check under the "Issues" tab.

Comment: NO WAY ! I found your answer very explanatory, I would never down vote  without a comment explaining why and despise people that do.  In fact I have never down voted any answer (or question for that matter) for any member.  I think anyone who answers a question is trying to help and anyone asking a question is seeking help.  I prefer to simply make a relevant comment. Since I believe your answer to be accurate and directly answers the question I have up voted it now.  I hope that is some consolation.  Thanks again for your kind assistance.

Comment: @kerry thanks for the kind words, and the up vote!